# Extracting PDF metadata in Python 3

Tags: python, metadata

What is the best module or easy script to get metadata from PDF files?
Everything seems like its for python 2.7 or the module wont work.
I need It for python 3.4.2 to work.

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer/ = Python 2.7
```

With PyPDF2:

With: `print(input1.getDocumentInfo())`
I keep getting errors:

```
raise utils.PdfReadError("file has not been decrypted")
PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: file has not been decrypted
```

Any tips or help?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the look of the error mesaage you are trying to read an encrypted PDF file. Until you provide a decryption password you won't get anything out of that file.

If you want a Python 3 version of `pdfminer` then try [`pdfminer3k`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer3k), which claims to be a Python 3 port.